# linq syntax to sql syntax

Tags: sql, string, linq

I have a aspx grid control that uses linq to query.  I can get the filter expression in a string from the grid control, but of course it's in linq.  linq and tsql are the same some of the time, but different other times.  I need to change linq string syntax to tsql syntax so I can query, get the same results in a dataset and load a custom maintenance form.  For example:

linq:  StartsWith([city], 'cedarburg')
Tsql:  city like '%cedarburg'

Is there a method to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This converting of syntax sounds like something you should not do yourself but leave to a query provider like linq-to-sql or linq-to-entities. What is to bigger picture?

Answer (score 0):

Download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and you can paste in your LINQ and then view the emitted SQL.  The other more difficult option is to point a SQL Profiler at your intended SQL server, fire off the line of LINQ and see what it emitted against the server.